# Listview repeating items with infinite scroll on Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, infinite-scroll

I built a listview and implemented an infinite scroll, the listview is limited to show 5 items per load until it reaches the end, but it is duplicating the initial 5 items, I'll add some image so you can understand better:

[image]

How can I fix it?

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout._fragment_clientes, container, false);

        rootView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT ));


        try {

            lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listaClientes);

            clientes = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();
            final ClientViewAdapter ad = new ClientViewAdapter(getActivity(), this, clientes);

            lv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
            lv.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);

            lv.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener(){
                @Override
                public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount) {
                    new LoadMoreClientTask(progressBar,FragmentClientes.this,ad,getActivity()).execute(page);
                }
            });

            lv.addFooterView(footerLinearLayout);


            lv.setAdapter(ad);
            new LoadMoreClientTask(progressBar,this,ad,getActivity()).execute(1);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rootView;
    }
```

The Adapter:

```
public class ClientViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private FragmentClientes frag;
    private List<ClienteModel> cliente;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

    public ClientViewAdapter(Context context, FragmentClientes fragmentClientes, List<ClienteModel> clientes) {
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from( context );
        this.cliente = clientes;

        frag = fragmentClientes;

    }

    public int getCount() {

        return cliente.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cliente_item, null);
            holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.clienteId);
            holder.nome = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.clienteNome);
            holder.tipo = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.clienteTipo);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)vi.getTag();
        }

        ClienteModel item = new ClienteModel();
        item = cliente.get(position);

        holder.id.setText(String.valueOf(item.getClientes_id()));
        holder.nome.setText(item.getNome());
        holder.tipo.setText(item.getTipo());

        return vi;
    }

    public void setData(List<ClienteModel> clientes){
        this.cliente.addAll(clientes);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class ViewHolder
    {
        TextView id;
        TextView nome;
        TextView tipo;

    }
}
```

And the LoadMoreTask snippet that gets the data from the database:

```
  protected Boolean doInBackground(Integer... parameters) {
        int npagina = parameters[0];
        cliente= new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();

        try {

            Repositorio mRepositorio = new Repositorio(context);


            List listaDeClientes = mRepositorio.getClientes(npagina,5,"");

            cliente = listaDeClientes;

            System.out.println("pagina " + npagina);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Function getClientes:

```
 public List<ClienteModel> getClientes(Integer pagina, Integer limit, String consulta) throws SQLException {

        Integer offset = pagina * limit - limit;


        List<ClienteModel> listaDeRegistros = new ArrayList<ClienteModel>();



        if(consulta.isEmpty()) {
            query = "SELECT * FROM " + tabelaCLIENTES + " WHERE credencial_id = " + mSessao.getString("id_credencial") + " LIMIT " + offset + ", " + limit;
        }else {
            query = "SELECT * FROM " + tabelaCLIENTES + " WHERE (credencial_id = " + mSessao.getString("id_credencial") + ") and (nome LIKE '%"+consulta+"%') LIMIT " + offset + ", " + limit;
        }

        System.out.println(query);

        try {

            Cursor mCursor = bd.rawQuery(query, null);

            if (mCursor.getCount() > 0) {
                if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        ClienteModel mClienteModel = new ClienteModel();

                        mClienteModel.setClientes_id(mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna.CLIENTES_ID)));
                        mClienteModel.setId_rm(mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna.ID_RM)));
                        mClienteModel.setCredencial_id(mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna.CREDENCIAL_ID)));
                        mClienteModel.setNome(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna.NOME)));
                        mClienteModel.setTipo(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna.TIPO)));
                        mClienteModel.setInformacao_adicional(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna.INFORMACAO_ADICIONAL)));
                        mClienteModel.set_criado(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna._CRIADO)));
                        mClienteModel.set_modificado(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna._MODIFICADO)));
                        mClienteModel.set_status(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ClienteModel.Coluna._STATUS)));

                        listaDeRegistros.add(mClienteModel);

                    } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return listaDeRegistros;
    }
```

Comment: what's `System.out.println("pagina " + npagina);` printing? Is it incrementing everytime you scroll down?

Comment: @Leo yes, as I scroll down the number of the page is increasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are hitting the end to load more, your load code is just re-loading the same 5 entries. You need to check what you have already loaded and validate if it is the end or not to stop adding entries.

Comment: Sincerely I don't have a clue on how to do that, can you give me more details?

Comment: Without seeing the code of `mRepositorio.getClientes`, I would say that in there it is just doing some sort of retrieval without looking into if those had already been retrieved or not.

Comment: I just added the getClientes function, see something wrong? Thank you for your help

Comment: @AndrewBreen without seen the code of `getClientes` either I have to assume that the hard-coded 5 is the page size (number of items per page) and that `npagina` is the page number which hopefully is getting incremented. So, based on this assumption your answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

try this one (exchange limit with offset):

```
query = "SELECT * FROM " + tabelaCLIENTES + " WHERE credencial_id = " + mSessao.getString("id_credencial") + " LIMIT " + limit + ", " + offset;
```

Comment: where do you get 'EndlessScrollListener()' from?